# How do I add claims from a LinqToSql list?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin, claims-based-identity

I have created an application that uses Active Directory and Owin to authenticate my users. The scope of the application requires that I use roles defined in an existing CMS database to authorize users within the custom application. Here is what I have tried:

```
CMSContext _cms = new CMSContext();
var user = @"STRING\" + userPrincipal.Name;
var result = (from rls in _cms.CMSRoles
              join urs in _cms.CMSUserRoles on rls.RoleID equals urs.RoleID
              join usrs in _cms.CMSUser on urs.UserID equals usrs.UserID
              where usrs.Username == user
              select rls.RoleName).ToList();
//using foreach to get roles one by one
foreach(var @group in groups)
{
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, @groups.?));
}
```

I apologize in advance for the question mark, but it is currently where I am getting stuck. I cannot find, nor think of anything to use that would allow me to pull them out in sequence in this for loop. I am trying to follow what I would normally do if I were adding claims from AD, which is simply:

```
var groups = userPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups();
foreach (var @group in groups)
{
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, @group.Name));
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since you selected RoleName, which I assume is just a string, I would expect you would just use the `group` value: `identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, @group));`

Comment: He is not `foreach`ing over `result`s but over `groups` which is not being disclosed in his code sample. @Skullomania - where comes `groups` from?

Comment: @PatrickArtner that was part of my issue it should have been result. I have figured it out and will post the solution shortly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was looking for the `@group` name so it needs cast to a string. See the following:

```
CMSContext _cms = new CMSContext();
var user = @"STRING\" + userPrincipal.Name;
var result = (from rls in _cms.CMSRoles
          join urs in _cms.CMSUserRoles on rls.RoleID equals urs.RoleID
          join usrs in _cms.CMSUser on urs.UserID equals usrs.UserID
          where usrs.Username == user
          select rls.RoleName).ToList();
//using foreach to get roles one by one
foreach(var @group in groups)
{
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, @group.ToString()));
}
```